# How to cycle among all live buffers?

Tags: buffers

Emacs 26.2 `M-C-L` is bound to `switch-to-next-buffer`.  I have many files open but it's simply flopping between two.  On my old XEmacs the same key cycled through all of them (and `S-M-C-L` did so backwards).  I can't use that any more to find the exact function it was bound to.

Do I need a different function?  Or does this function need an argument?  (It seems to have no documentation.)

(To be clear: I have only one window open and it is not split in two.)

Comment: Does `next-buffer` `C-x <RIGHT>` and `previous-buffer` `C-x <LEFT>` behave the way you want?  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Select-Buffer.html

Comment: C-x <left> does what I want to do, thanks!  C-x <right> is just alternating between two buffers though.

Comment: `switch-to-next-buffer` is not bound to a key by default, and is explicitly designed to switch between **recent** windows, which is the behaviour you are describing. `next-buffer` and `previous-buffer` should do what you want, as lawlist points out. If `C-x <right>` isn't doing what you want, check to see that it is actually bound to `next-buffer`; maybe there's something in your config that has altered that binding too.

Comment: This question is likely a duplicate, but I can't find the dup quickly. Anyone?

Comment: > This question is likely a duplicate, but I can't find the dup quickly...  Actually I think it's a bit weirder problem: my C-x <RIGHT> is only cycling between two files even though I have 10 open.  It seems like somethings actually buggy or I broke it somehow.  In other words, my issue isn't the one I thought it was...

Comment: > If C-x <right> isn't doing what you want, check to see that it is actually bound to next-buffer; maybe there's something in your config that has altered that binding too....  Thx Tyler.  I confirm it is indeed bound to next-buffer, and I DO have 10 files open, and next-buffer is only switching between two of them...

Answer (score 1):

Emacs provides two built-in functions named `next-buffer` with a default binding of `C-x <RIGHT>` and `previous-buffer` with a default binding of `C-x <LEFT>`:

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Select-Buffer.html

Comment: thanks but next-buffer is not working as expected.  If I have 10 files open it should cycle between all 10, right?  It is only cycling between 2.

Comment: @SwissFrank Could you run `emacs -Q` and test this again?  The default behaviour *should* be what you want it to be.  If it only happens with your config, then something in your config must be changing the behaviour.

Comment: Thanks Phils... this is pretty much the answer; if you write it up as such I'll select as answer.  With -Q, C-x <right> works correctly.  Without -Q, it doesn't work.  The cause is that I had defined my own function: (defun switch-to-next-buffer () (interactive) (switch-to-buffer (other-buffer))) earlier, when experimenting I guess, and I left it defined but forgot about it.  And I guess this switch-to-next-buffer is internally called by next-buffer (which is the binding for my C-x<right> according to ctrl-h ? c).

Answer (score 0):

Try using `bs-cycle-previous`, `bs-cycle-next` which come with emacs.
These use cycling rules you can configure, check their help to see options.